# WHM, default Exim config - sent mail not being delivered to Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, exim, dedicated-server

I'm having a huge headache with email over the past week and i'm ready to take a lump hammer to the server!

We have a dedicated server with WHM installed and currently using the default exim configuration, and everything works fantastic, until it comes to sending mail to an email hosted through Microsoft Exchange!

All emails in and out of the server are showing as accepted and delivered without error, there are no bounce backs so i'm at a complete loss as to what the issue is, i am however almost certain it is a server issue.

We have tested half a dozen domain emails hosted on the server and sent to two completely different clients who we know both use Exchange. Both clients have had their IT support companies look into possible causes and so far nobody has been able to explain why out emails are not getting through.

If anyone can make any suggestions or possible solutions they will be very much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have the Exchange admins use the message tracking feature to figure out what's going on.  I've yet to see it miss - if their servers are receiving the emails, the [message tracking logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc539064.aspx) contain a lot of details  that will enable the admins to figure out what's happening to the emails after they hit the Exchange server.

If there's no record of the messages in the tracking logs, then they're not arriving, and your problem lies somewhere between the two mail servers.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, i'll pass it onto their IT support and hopefully shed some light, will report back soon!

Comment: @Danny You should give them exact sender and date of mail and their side ID's logged in Exim mainlog as C="" - if you not see it in you logs then you should add `smtp_confirmation` to `log_selector` (or event better - set it to `all`). Exim log there answer to `.` ending mail and this is ID of email in remote system - for Exchange something like: C="250 2.6.0 <00fd01ce2933$fbffa870$f3fef950$@yourcompany.com> [InternalId=10398003] Queued mail for d" - this probably speedup search.