# How to Fix Microsoft Exchange incoming emails always failing with DKIM bodyhash mismatch

Tags: email, exchange, exim, dkim

I am noticing on our servers that since we set DKIM to reject failures on Exim (v4.95) that a LOT of genuine emails are being rejected.

Looking at the Exim rejectlogs we see that persistantly these emails are rejected if they're being handled by Microsoft Exchange/ OutlookProtection Servers:

**Exim Rejectlog:**

```
2022-06-27 11:36:33 1o5m5d-0006bD-82 H=mail-eopbgr20129.outbound.protection.outlook.com (EUR02-VE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com) [42.107.2.129]:54704 X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=no rejected DKIM : 
DKIM: encountered the following problem validating 01473280699.onmicrosoft.com: bodyhash_mismatch
Envelope-from: <******@######.co.uk>
Envelope-to: <******@_!_!_!_!_!_.co.uk>
P Received: from mail-eopbgr20129.outbound.protection.outlook.com ([42.107.2.129]:54704 helo=EUR02-VE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com)
    by base.ourServer.co.uk with esmtps  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.95)
    (envelope-from <******@######.co.uk>)
    id 1o5m5d-0006bD-82
    for ******@_!_!_!_!_!_.co.uk;
    Mon, 27 Jun 2022 11:36:33 +0100
  ARC-Seal: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=fail;
```

See:

**DKIM: encountered the following problem validating 01473280699.onmicrosoft.com: bodyhash_mismatch**

This only happens with messages coming from addresses via `outbound.protection.outlook.com` and similar variations.

Another similar -but not identical- example:

**Exim rejectlog:**

```
2022-06-17 12:29:04 1o14hL-0005Jq-Jy H=mail12.rbs.com (remlvdmzma04.rbs.com) [159.136.80.93]:56531 X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=no rejected DKIM : DKIM: encountered the following problem validating rbsworkspace.onmicrosoft.com: bodyhash_mismatch
Envelope-from: <prvs=1573f1310=named@domain.com>
Envelope-to: <******@_!_!_!_!_!_.co.uk>
P Received: from mail12.rbs.com ([159.136.80.93]:56531 helo=remlvdmzma04.rbs.com)
    by base.ourServer.co.uk with esmtps  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.95)
    (envelope-from <prvs=1573f1310=named@domain.com>)
    id 1o14hL-0005Jq-Jy
    for ******@_!_!_!_!_!_.co.uk;
    Fri, 17 Jun 2022 12:29:04 +0100
  DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple;
  d=domain.com; i=@domain.com; q=dns/txt; s=mail;
  t=1655206023; x=1686742023;
  h=from:to:subject:date:message-id:mime-version;
  bh=3k6znbu3nEVhMGEdZiqBMSTBU7K2v4atTAzapxLvBCU=;
  b=YzXTzO3up95x48MLGbmJPHw5k7nAeWwYzPKK5rJMX1LG7EjERZjRw/vQ
   +H50m8i3SDz0DuGrK5EvvzzSjhfgMlxJLqulwcuZw4Bp9v9lH5tgWS7Pv
   PFHQtkSIvK/TdVQj4x9jGkbBwfHVHu/qgGuyf0TJZ6CN9gHY/HFzA5t3d
   c=;
  IronPort-SDR: K+m4jq9fjUdFtsVbXA4w4YGnRoyY21aiv3bXAqTxQjy8TsSiXwdkT0lOHAASchcRl0oaoR3Fgk
 u2Bcyi5/macn4gIof7lWGxgasR0Ct/xTY=
  X-IronPort-AV: E=Sophos;i="5.91,300,1647302400"; 
   d="png'150?scan'150,208,217,150";a="34252307"
```

See:

**DKIM: encountered the following problem validating rbsworkspace.onmicrosoft.com: bodyhash_mismatch**

I have read various posts [on here](https://serverfault.com/questions/491179/whm-default-exim-config-sent-mail-not-being-delivered-to-microsoft-exchange), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384797/exims-dkim-signatures-do-not-verify-on-microsoft-servers-outlook-hotmail-on), and [Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dkim-keys-fail/544710b9-c389-4442-a883-bb400db3c0ad) (who interestingly concluded the issue was at the receivers end rather than them incorrectly setting up their email servers) and [elsewhere](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f7c15343-28d4-4825-a6db-0a2a3017642c/message-body-changed-dkim-fails-when-using-exchange-online), [elsewhere](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234534-how-does-one-fix-dkim-issues-with-office-365-email).

---

so, my question is:

## Can I do anything with Exim at the receiving end to permit Microsft Exchange caused DKIM bodyhash mismatches?

Otherwise Exim can never refuse DKIM failures....

*qualifier:* I assume the cause is MS Exchange as the `outlook.com` domain is present on ALL body hash mismatch emails in the rejectlogs, but I'm not familair with MicroSoft's architecture so I've mentally grouped all the above as "exchange server" issues, as that's my perception. I may be incorrect.

Comment: A message transferred via an indirect email stream (forwarded, via mailing list, etc.) could always have headers added or changed or be otherwise modified in some way, making the DKIM signature fail. Generally, I don’t believe rejecting such messages outright is advisable.

Comment: @glts I disagree. the whole point of DKIM is that an email is sent and is signed that it is a legitimate genuine mail. To not fail DKIM signatures/checks/whatever makes the whole concept of DKIM redundant (conceptually at least).